# Realizar consulta de búsqueda en base de datos en 3 columnas distintas

Tags: php

Estoy intentando realizar una búsqueda en la base de datos, que no sólo me compruebe si esa palabra está dentro de una columna, sino en tres. Estoy probando con:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art WHERE juego_asociado OR titulo OR etiquetas LIKE :busqueda ORDER BY fecha_publicacion DESC");
$statement->execute(array(':busqueda' => "%$busqueda%"));
$noticias = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Algo tengo mal en el código porque no me da los resultados correctos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la manera correcta de tu consulta es hacer un `LIKE` por cada columna.

```
SELECT * FROM art WHERE juego_asociado LIKE :busqueda OR titulo LIKE :busqueda OR etiquetas LIKE :busqueda ORDER BY fecha_publicacion DESC ;
```

Tambien hay alternativas como `CONCAT_WS`

```
SELECT * FROM art WHERE CONCAT_WS('', juego_asociado, titulo, etiquetas) LIKE :busqueda
```

Hay pruebas que se han realizado entre la diferencia de `OR` y `CONCAT_WS` en que esta ultima, ha tenido mejor tiempo de respuesta que un `OR` pero para consultas mas robustas o con mas condiciones no es lo mas optimo. Mi opción sigue siendo el `OR` por cada columna.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!